# Instant run not working on Google pixel 2xl runing android 9.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-instant-run

Install run not working on google pixel 2xl, I can see a notification in the android studio "instant Run applied code changes and restarted the current activity" but I'm not seeing any changes in my device, I have Samsung device in witch instant run work fine. Any idea how to fix this problem in my google pixel xl2?

Comment: Can you add logcat logs?

Comment: from the android studio? i don't see any helpfull logs related to instant  run in my logs

Answer (score 0):

Instant Run gave me grief when debugging in Studio 3.4. Just turning it off worked (File->Settings->Build->Instant Run), but bothered me that was the 'solution'.

I felt better about it after reading this however: https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/01/android-studio-35-canary-1-available.html

"Canary 1 of Android Studio 3.5 introduces a preview of Apply Changes, which replaces Instant Run. We know that Instant Run has in the past caused issues for many of you, and the feature hasn’t lived up to our quality standards. Instant Run rewrote the bytecode of your APK at build time to inject hooks to replace classes on the fly. For simple apps, this was largely fine, but for more complex apps, this could result in longer build times or head-scratching errors caused by conflicts between your app and Instant Run’s build process.
We’ve taken a step back and decided to rewrite it from the ground up."